# Bash variable in pagekite startup command

Tags: python, bash

I have my own pagekite.py frontend at `kite.mydomain.com` I'm trying to start pagekite.py with a bash script on an older FreeBSD machine and can't seem to get this right. The first line of `systemname.txt` contains the internalID of the system. I'm then trying to start the backend of pagekite.py at `internalID.kite.mydomain.com` but this does not seem to work?

```
#!/bin/sh
sid=`head -n 1 /usr/local/www/systemname.txt`
python /usr/local/pagekite/pagekite.py --frontend=kite.mydomain.com:8080 --service_on=http:$sid.kite.mydomain.com:localhost:80:MYSECRETHASH &
```

When I manually run the command, it works just fine.

```
python /usr/local/pagekite/pagekite.py --frontend=kite.mydomain.com:8080 --service_on=http:internalID.kite.mydomain.com:localhost:80:MYSECRETHASH &
```

Comment: and I have added an `echo $sid` line to see if it was getting the right information, and it definitely printed the id I was looking for...

Comment: Does the Python generate any error messages?  Have you tried adding debugging statements into `pagekite.py`?  Something like `print sys.argv`.

Comment: It's prewritten by pagekite.net the source is at http://pagekite.net/pk/pagekite.py

Comment: OK, I think I found the problem... the line returns in the shell script had gotten turned in to some crazy characters, so the whole thing was just messing up! fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Any chance the shell script was created on a windows box, then copied to the FreeBSD machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have text files that were created on a windows box, lines are delimited with `\r\n`.  Unix (Linux, OSX, *BSD) likes its lines delimited with just `\n` and scripts can fail in odd ways if they are not.

You can convert from one to the other with the [`dos2unix` and `unix2dos` utilities](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_dos2uni.htm).